# C++: Error passing const pointer of const reference

Tags: c++

I have C++ code that when I compile it I get the following error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘DataSourceScheme::initObject(const QString&, const QString&, QVector<ColumnScheme*>* const&)’
  initObject(datasourcescheme.name_, datasourcescheme.cmd_, datasourcescheme.columns_);

 note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘QVector<ColumnScheme*>* const’ to ‘const QVector<const ColumnScheme*>*
```

The C++ code:

```
DataSourceScheme::DataSourceScheme(const DataSourceScheme &datasourcescheme) {
    initObject(datasourcescheme.name_, datasourcescheme.cmd_, datasourcescheme.columns_);   
}

void DataSourceScheme::initObject(const QString &name, const QString &cmd, const QVector<const ColumnScheme*> *columns) {
    name_ = name;
    cmd_ = cmd;
    columns_ = new QVector<ColumnScheme*>();
    if (columns != NULL) {
        for (const ColumnScheme *column : *columns) {
            addColumn(*column);
        }       
    }
}
```

Please help

Thanks!

Comment: `QVector<ColumnScheme*>` and `QVector<const ColumnScheme*>` are distinct types

Comment: Holy [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html) batman.

Comment: What does it mean? What should I do in order to pass the parameter with the correct type?

Comment: either change the parameter's declaration of the method the vector is passed to, or change the argument's type

Comment: @SomethingSomething _"What should I do in order to pass the parameter with the correct type?"_ May be you simply can't for this situation, and it's not intended to do so.

Comment: @PiotrS. change to what? `QVector<ColumnScheme*>* const` ?

Comment: depends on what you intend to do, start with `QVector<ColumnScheme*> *columns`, but from what I can see this will trigger another error in your range based for loop that takes off pointers to `const` and puts them to collection of non-const

Comment: The problem here is that `.columns_` is a member of a const reference, and somehow it is translated to something different from const pointer...

Comment: I expect to get `const QVector<const ColumnScheme*>*`, but it sends me `QVector<ColumnScheme*>* const`

Comment: who *sends* you? you do it. also, you can drop the trailing `const`

Comment: @SomethingSomething Review the link I gave you and think carefully about where const belongs.

Comment: @SomethingSomething the constness of vector itself results in const pointers it holds, not constness of objects the pointers point to

Comment: Finally I succeeded compiling it by removing the `const` from the template. I.e., I declared the columns as `const QVector<ColumnScheme*> *`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need clarification on the usage of const. `foo* const A` declares an object of type foo and creates a constant pointer to that object. The object can be changed but not the pointer. `const foo*` creates a pointer to a constant object. The object foo is not modifiable.

You are trying to pass a constant pointer to a list of editable objects to a function which requires a pointer to a list of constant objects. Do you see where this leads to problems? The usage within the function does not match the criteria set at the creation of the objects being passed.

You can pass a normal pointer to a function requiring a constant pointer. This conversion is OK, i.e.

```
    void func(foo* const param); // Function declaration        
    foo* A;
    func(A); // Function call OK
```

Also,

```
    void func(foo* const param); // Function declaration        
    foo* const A;
    func(A); // Function call OK
```

You cannot pass a pointer to a constant object to a function requiring a normal pointer. This conversion is OK, i.e.

```
    void func(foo* param); // Function declaration        
    const foo* A;
    func(A); // Error
```

I will add a side note. The use of `void func(foo* const param);` is good practice IMHO to signify that the function `func` is not expected to delete, manage memory, or reassign the pointer. This is why many microsoft API calls use the const keyword. They merely use the object but in no way manage it.